# Getting a NaN-error and I do not know how to solve it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write out a price but I get a NaN-error. The code looks like this. Does anyone have any ideas? 
i have tried using parseFloat but i dont really do anything.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var interest = 4.5;

    var price = parseInt($('div-car-price').data('carprice'));

    var defaultPricePerMonth = price / 36 * interest;

    $('span.result').text(defaultPricePerMonth + ' kr');

    $('#months').on('change', function () {

        var selectedPeriod = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

        var calculatedPrice = price / selectedPeriod * interest;

        $('span.result').text(calculatedPrice + ' kr');



    });


});
```

and this is how my cshtml look like.

```
<div class="">
      <h1 class="display-4">@Model.Model</h1>
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">

       <div class="card-body car-price" data-carprice="@Model.Price">
           Bil: @Model.Model <br />
           Pris: @Model.Price.ToString("C");

       </div>

    </div>
    <strong><br />
    Finansiering

    </strong> <br />

    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">

                <label for="months">Avbetalningsperiod (månader)</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="months">
                    <option value="12">12</option>
                    <option value="24">24</option>
                    <option value="36" selected>36</option>
                    <option value="48">48</option>
                    <option value="60">60</option>

                </select>

            </div>
           </div>
            Kr/Månad: <span class="result"></span>

        </div>



    </div>

  </div>
```

so any one have any ideas,
also i got helped with this.
so thank you all for your help!

Comment: Where's the NaN error - which line, or which value? Can you verify that you have finite numbers for price and selectedPeriod read from your page?

Comment: `NaN` is not an error, it's a value.

Comment: `.val()` will always return a string.

Comment: Share your html also, so that we can reproduce this issue ?

Comment: `'div-car-price'` is not a valid CSS selector

Comment: Most likely `var price = parseInt($('div-car-price').data('carprice'))` ends up as `NaN`

Comment: Also likely: `$(this).find('option:selected').val()` returns a string, so when you try to `price / selectedPeriod * interest` it gives `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var price = parseInt($('div-car-price').data('carprice'));
```

Here (div-car-price) should be a valide selector like class or id.

```
var selectedPeriod = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

Above line Should be like this;

```
var selectedPeriod = parseInt($(this).find('option:selected').val());
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to mark the the answer as correct.

Comment: A full solution would additionally _check_ for `isNaN` and set to 0, or similar....